# Connected two line using svg in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I draw two line using svg, but when I render it, I only view one line and the other can't be seen. I dont know how to append that two line and make it all seen. That two line supposed to be seen when I click a polygon. Can anyone help me?

Here's my code

```
          var group = evt.target.parentNode;
      // Get the bounding box of the group
      var bbox = group.getBBox();
      // Add a triangle to the group
      var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
      var line = document.createElementNS(svgns, "line");
      var line2 = document.createElementNS(svgns, "line");
      line.setAttribute('id','line2');
    line.setAttribute('x1','0');
    line.setAttribute('y1','0');
    line.setAttribute('x2','5');
    line.setAttribute('y2','19');
    line.setAttribute("stroke", "black")
    line2.setAttribute('id','line2');
    line2.setAttribute('x1', '7');
    line2.setAttribute('y1','5');
    line2.setAttribute('x2','5');
    line2.setAttribute('y2','19');
    line2.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
      var xPos = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;  
      var yPos = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;     
      line2.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + xPos + "," + yPos + ")");
      group.appendChild(line2);
```

Comment: You've also given both lines the same id value, which is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are appending `line2` to the group.

```
group.appendChild(line2);
```

But where is the `appendChild()` call for the other line?